# Depreciation Warning with Dateutil _timelex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series

So I have been using a function to merge time series data, and just yesterday I started seeing this depreciation error when using it:

```
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Hydrostats_tests\venv1\lib\site-
packages\dateutil\parser\__init__.py:46: 
DeprecationWarning: _timelex is a 
private class and may break without warning, 
it will be moved and or renamed in future versions. warnings.warn(msg, 
DeprecationWarning)
```

The code I am running is below, and I am using a package that I made.

```
import os
import hydrostats.data as hd

sim_dir = r'C:\Users\user\Documents\Data\interim_raw_data'
obs_dir = r'C:\Users\user\Documents\Data\recorded_raw_data'

sim_path = [os.path.join(sim_dir, d) for d in os.listdir(sim_dir)]
obs_path = [os.path.join(obs_dir, d) for d in os.listdir(obs_dir)]


visual_df = hd.merge_data(sim_path[0], obs_path[0])
```

Here is the merge data function:

```
def merge_data(predicted_file_path, recorded_file_path, interpolate=None, column_names=['Simulated', 'Observed'],
               predicted_tz=None, recorded_tz=None, interp_type='pchip'):

    if predicted_tz is None and recorded_tz:

        print('Either Both Timezones are required or neither')

    elif predicted_tz and recorded_tz is None:

        print('Either Both Timezones are required or neither')

    elif predicted_tz is None and recorded_tz is None and interpolate is None:

        # Importing data into a data-frame
        df_predicted = pd.read_csv(predicted_file_path, delimiter=",", header=None, names=[column_names[0]],
                                   index_col=0, infer_datetime_format=True, skiprows=1)
        df_recorded = pd.read_csv(recorded_file_path, delimiter=",", header=None, names=[column_names[1]],
                                  index_col=0, infer_datetime_format=True, skiprows=1)
        # Converting the index to datetime type
        df_recorded.index = pd.to_datetime(df_recorded.index, infer_datetime_format=True)
        df_predicted.index = pd.to_datetime(df_predicted.index, infer_datetime_format=True)

        return pd.DataFrame.join(df_predicted, df_recorded).dropna()
```

The error occurs at these two lines

**df_recorded.index=pd.to_datetime(df_recorded.index,infer_datetime_format=True)**
**df_predicted.index=pd.to_datetime(df_predicted.index,infer_datetime_format=True)**

The csv data that I am reading looks like this:

```
Datetime,recorded streamflow (m^3/s)
1962-02-23,160.0
1962-02-24,163.0
1962-02-25,178.0
1962-02-26,169.0
1962-02-27,169.0
1962-02-28,169.0
1962-03-01,169.0
1962-03-02,163.0
1962-03-03,160.0
1962-03-04,158.0
1962-03-05,195.0
```

I have looked for this error online, and I have tried to use the debugger, but I haven't been able to see the source of this error. I guess there was an update but I'm not sure what was updated to cause this error.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: ... it isn't an error. It's a _warning_. Your code may break if you update the library again. It's not that you did anything wrong, just be aware that the method you're using won't be available in later versions of the library.

Comment: Good point, I edited the title

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18141

Comment: It looks like Pandas already knows about this, so most likely this will not become a problem as long as you don't update `dateutil` before updating to a future version of `pandas`.